# My dryer outlet is a NEMA 10-30, wired with the "Neutral" connection wired to ground. What should I do to make this safe?

Tags: electrical, safety, dryer

Long story short, I recently learned about NEMA 10-30 plugs being unsafe, and I noticed my dryer outlet is a 10-30. I wanted to replace it with a proper 14-30 plug, but when I took it apart I noticed that the wiring to the dryer is actually Romex 10/2, using the white and the black as the two power lines, and wiring the ground to the neutral plug.

Now that I know about this, I want to make this safe. Is there an option that I can do that will make this safe at all short of running a new proper wire to the dryer, or do I need to run a new wire? Thanks!

Comment: Problem is that a bare ground is never a good substitute for neutral in a branch circuit. If it was the other way around - 3 insulated conductors but no separate ground - then there would be a possible alternative of a GFCI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Discovered 10/2 wired 3-prong receptacle for dryer. Is it ok to leave as is?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/125211/discovered-10-2-wired-3-prong-receptacle-for-dryer-is-it-ok-to-leave-as-is)

I agree with all of the answers in the previous posted question that asked the same question:
No you can not modify it to make it any safer than it is. Yes you should change it to the proper 10/3 wiring and a NEMA 14-30 receptacle for safety.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was hoping it was at least possible to wire this as a NEMA 6-30 and use that to power the dryer somehow. Oh well, thanks! Sad that this was the original builder who did this, and likely circa 1998...

Comment: And it only seems to be getting worse unfortunately! Between the lack of good help and knowledge and the lack of quality products we are in a sad state for sure!!

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto  The problem with dryers is they need neutral to run the 120v motor that turns the drum.  If they were pure 240v then a 6-30 would work.

Comment: @SOHR instead of linking a duplicate question in your own answer, the accepted practice it to note it in the comments on the original question. Once you have enough rep, you'll be able to Vote to Close (VtC) as a duplicate, as this question now stands. Until you have enough rep, your comment will serve as a notice to others who do have the rep to make the VtC

Comment: Got it FreeMan. Thanks!